# Elasticsearch lower than existing field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticsearch structure

```
[{product: 'product 1', price: 100, originalPrice: 150}]
```

How can i do a where query like this (sql): `select * from products where price < originalPrice` to find all products that have a discount

Answer (score 1):

The hardcore non-optimal under-performing way of doing it is to use a [`script` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) like this:

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "doc.price.value < doc.originalPrice.value",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A much better way would be to index that information into the document in a new boolean field, i.e. `"discounted": true` in your case.

```
{ 
    "product": "product 1", 
    "price": 100, 
    "originalPrice": 150,
    "discounted": true
}
```

Then it'll be much easier and to make a simple `term` query, which in addition will run much faster.

```
POST /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "term" : {
                    "discounted" : true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```